# Is there an end on the mini levels in PSP Little Big Planet?

Tags: psp, little-big-planet-psp

I have tried to play levels like Shear Madness and Double Dragons until they end, but never reach it. Should I keep trying or is there no end to reach?

**Edit**

Turns out that there is an end. I finished one of them and got the level complete symbol.

Answer (score 3):

The mini levels seem to be more about achieving a high score than having a definitive end - they basically keep going until you fail.

Comment: I noticed when you look at the creator curators it has the achievement symbols for the region next to their picture. So if you get the level complete symbol next to all the levels, by completing all the levels, in the region it will show the level complete symbol next to the creator curator's picture. I assume the same goes for the goodies and ace achievement symbols.